# merging datastreams using O(1) RAM

Tags: sorting, data-structures, merge, computer-science

How can I merge k sorted data streams using O(1) RAM ? How should I define the data stream object and its related functions/operations ?

My solution : Well I thought of using array lists as the data stream object. I planned to find the minimum value of the 0th index of the k array lists.The minimum value should be removed from that array list and should be put it in the output array list. This process should be repeated until all the k array lists have become null.But I guess this would take O(k*length of each array list). Any ideas how to do it in O(1) ?

Answer (score 1):

Making an O(1) ram algorithm is very dependent on your underlying datastructure and language of choice. Assuming you know how to manipulate your data structure with O(1) ram see this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

The merging function takes O(1) memory. Now all you need is an index into your set of data streams and merge all streams into the first stream and you are done.

Comment: So the merge(left,right) which is called in the last line of merge_sort(list m) is O(1), but if we look at the inside code of the merge function shouldn't it be O(no. of elements in left + no. of elements in right) ? I am confused here, please help me out.